# Can I attach to a single container in a cluster when running docker-compose up?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Say that I have a few services specified in a docker-compose file, e.g. `web_1`, `web_2`, `db`, and I want to read some specific message such as an error message in the log for `web_1` that appears when it starts up. Is there any way to attach to a single container when I run `docker-compose` up?

If I run `docker-compose up` I will be attached to all containers, so that irrelevant log messages from the other services will clutter the terminal and move the message up too quickly. If I run `docker-compose up -d` and then `docker attach web_1`, it is too late, since the error message is printed right at start. I have also tried `docker-compose up -d && docker attach web_1` but the attach command is run before the container is running, so I only get a message saying "No such container".

Comment: Have you tried `docker-compose up -d` and then `docker logs ...`? Reference [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/)

Comment: you can use ```docker-compose up -d && sleep 5 && docker attach web_1```

Comment: @tgogos Yeah, it's probably the best solution at the moment

Comment: You can also use `docker-compose logs ...` which lets you select more than one containers (in case you are interested to see what's going on for 2 containers for example but with a single command). See the relative question: [Docker Compose selective attaching to services](https://serverfault.com/questions/892628/docker-compose-selective-attaching-to-services)

Comment: Ah, that's a good to know. Only problem it that the logs aren't live right from the start, otherwise I would consider that a valid answer